# Another pitch detection problem

Tags: fft, pitch, detection

I'm a french student and I have to make a scientific project in group, so we decided to work on how automatically turn sheets music when a musician reaches the end of the page. For that I'm working on pitch detection but my math/physics level doesn't allow me to understand everything (I'm 17 years old).

Now, I'm doing the FFT of a wave signal (microphone input) and get the peak. This works well with sinusoids and wind instruments but when I try whith a violin the results are weird (because there are a lot of harmonics stronger than my fundamental)...

So I have some questions :

- Can you recommend me a simple website explaining basic DSP or algorithms to do pitch detection ?
- Do you think that just a FFT will do the job ?
- There are a lot of methods to do what i want to achieve (autocorrelation, FFT, Cepstrum...), which is the best in my case ?

I really want to understand what I'm doing, that's why I'm coding everything instead of just use a library, but for the moment I'm really lost...

Thank you! (and excuse me for my poor english ^^)

Comment: Have you seen all related questions on this site? https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pitch

Comment: An FFT alone will not do the job.  However, FFTs might be useful as a sub-components of a pitch detection/estimation algorithm (such as cepstrums, etc.)  The best case depends on the sound.  Different methods work better with different types of sounds.  You will have to test against your data sets.

Comment: @MBaz Yeah I know, but each question is specific. Do you know where i can begin with dsp ? Simple dsp courses or lectures ?

Comment: If you want resources to get started, one of the best is "Understanding DSP" by Richard Lyons.

Comment: I was also having problems understanding some terms of DSP, one of the best ways to get started is to watch tutorials videos like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLuh62Q4Sv7BUSzx5Jr8Wrxxn-U10qG1et). This tutorial had helped me a lot to understand what digital signal is. DSP looks very scary at the beginning with its math, but it becomes very exciting when you start to realize what is what.